# How to make field as Read-Only inside Quick Edit list view when using modern UI

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, quick-edit, column-formatting

I have created a site column of type Single link of text, and i hide it from the New & Edit forms using this PnP script:-

```
$customfield.SetShowInEditForm($false)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
$customfield.SetShowInNewForm($false)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
$customfield.UpdateAndPushChanges($false)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

but still the field will be editable when using the list Quick Edit. 
Now in the classic UI, i use to create JSLINK and link it with the field which will cause the filed to be disabled inside the quick edit grid. here is the JSLINK i use to have:-

```
(function () {
    var overrideContext = {};
    overrideContext.Templates = overrideContext.Templates || {};
    overrideContext.Templates.OnPreRender = function(ctx) {
        var statusField = ctx.ListSchema.Field.filter(function(f) {
            return f.Name === 'ItemNumber';
        });
        if (statusField.length>0) {
            statusField[0].AllowGridEditing = false;
        }
    }
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext);
})();
```

but seems this approach will not work inside the modern UI. so can anyone advice on this?

Can I take benefit from the column formatting capability?

Comment: What is the data type of your field?

Comment: @GaneshSanap single link of text. i updated my question .. thanks

Comment: Do you want to use quick edit mode for this list? If no, you can disable it.

Comment: @GaneshSanap yes i want to use the quick edit ,, but i need to disable the field inside the quick edit (as i am setting its value inside a workflow)

Comment: @GaneshSanap can you advice if you find a fix for my issue..